# ActiveAdmin rails remove "New Object" button from header of index page specific resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

The index page for an ActiveAdmin resource by default contains a button to go to the form to create a new instance of that object

[image: Active Admin Header with New button]

I have a view with is a composite list of multiple times of items where a new button does not make sense. Is there a way to remove that button on only that resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Action do
  actions :all, except: :new
end
```

Something like that. Like that you can disable any action you desire

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not the exact solution because it also removes the `new` action and the `new route`.

If you are looking just to remove the button (and nothing more) then you should do this :

```
# item is an ActiveAdmin::ActionItem
config.action_items.delete_if {|item| item.name == :edit && item.display_on?(:show) }
```

Here i'm not displaying the `edit` button on the `show` page of my `resource`